# Multiple inheritance conflict

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual, multiple-inheritance, abstract

I have the following code:

```
class Interface
{
  virtual void method()=0;
};

class Base : public Interface
{
  virtual void method()
  {
    //implementation here
  }
};

class Parent: public Interface
{

};

class Child : public Base, public Parent
{

};

int main()
{
  Child c;//ERROR: cannot instantiate abstract class
}
```

Now I know why this is happening, since I'm inheriting Parent then I have to implement method again. But it's already defined in Base class and I don't want to override that definition for every child class. I think there was some standard way of getting rid of this in c++ (telling compiler which copy of Interface should it use) I just can't remember what it was.

Comment: Isn't it the case that without virtual inheritance, here you end up with two distinct virtual `method()` functions in your `Child` class?

Comment: I believe so, trying that right now.

Comment: Why do you want to inherit from both `Base` and `Parent`?

Comment: I guess part of my question is: Is it intentional that you're not using virtual inheritance in this diamond-shaped hierarchy?

Comment: @0A0D fair question but it'd take us off topic, let's just say I need to do this.

Comment: @NPE yes, and virtual keyword solved it. It was actually what I couldn't remeber, add your answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @AtoMerZ: Glad to hear this helped. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a diamond-shaped hierarchy but are not using virtual inheritance.

As a result, you end up with two distinct virtual `method()` functions in your `Child` class.

One way to fix it is to move to using virtual inheritance. This way you'll only have a single `Child::method()` and won't need two implementations.

Comment: "You have a diamond-shaped hierarchy but are not using virtual inheritance." That is, the code does **not** have a diamond-shaped hierarchy. For interfaces, the solution is, as you say, to turn the hierarchy into a diamond by deriving virtually from the interface class.

Comment: @PeteBecker `to turn the hierarchy into a diamond by deriving virtually from the interface class.` Nicely put, I hadn't thought of it that way :P

Answer (score 4):

What you are talking about is called [dominance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_%28C++%29).

From the linked article:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual void function();
};

class Child1 : public virtual Parent
{
public:
    void function();
};

class Child2 : public virtual Parent
{
};

class Grandchild : public Child1, public Child2
{
public:
    Grandchild()
    {
        function();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure virtual functions must be defined in the derived class.
If you don't do so, your derived class (in this case "child") will itself become an abstract class which can't be instantiated and hence the error.